# Open ball and Riemannian manifold

Tags: general-topology

As i know that a $n$ dimensional open ball is homeomorphic to $n$ dimensional euclidean space. It may be imply the Riemannian manifold is locally homeomorphic to the open ball. My questions as follows some open ball and homeomorphism in the Riemannian manifold.

1. A Riemannian manifold is $M$. Is $M$ has finite covers of open ball?
2. A subset of $M, U$, consists of union of open balls. Is $U$ homeomorphic to $M$?

thanks.

Comment: 1. It depends on whether by "open ball" you mean an open subset homeomorphic to the open ball or an open ball with respect to the metric. If the latter, then no; take for example $\mathbb{R}$. 2. No, take a union of two open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks.